# Cannot Connect to socket.io laravel swoole

Tags: laravel, websocket, socket.io, laravel-6, swoole

```js
let socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:1215/', {transports: ['websocket']});
```

i serve my laravel application with php swoole

```php
php artisan swoole:http start
```

i always get this error in console

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:1215/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Comment: So the web server returns 404. This seems self-explanatory.

Comment: i cant find why return 404 all routes ok

Answer (score 0):

Go to /config/swoole_http.php (dont forget to run vendor:publish)

```
'websocket' => [
    'enabled' => env('SWOOLE_HTTP_WEBSOCKET', true),
],
```